# Missing correlations in CFA in R

Tags: r, correlation, factor-analysis

I am estimating a CFA in R, using the lavaan package. When computing the parameter estimates, I get the full list, but without the latent factor subscale correlations.
Minimum working example code (given my dataset is correctly loaded and variables are correctly prepared etc.):

```
library(lavaan)

EL_cfa <- "EL_cfa <- "EL =~ ELM + ELP + ELC
ELM =~ EL_01 + EL_02 + EL_03
ELP =~ EL_04 + EL_05
ELC =~ EL_06 + EL_07
fit_EL_cfa <- cfa(EL_cfa, data = Exampledata, std.lv = TRUE, missing = "fiml"))
summary(fit_EL_cfa, standardized = TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
parameterEstimates(fit_EL_cfa, standardized=TRUE)
```

With the last command, I get a result table with a lot of parameters, amongst others:

```
    lhs op  rhs    est se  z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper  std.lv st.all std.nox
...
36   EL ~~   EL  1.000  0 NA     NA        1        1   1.000  1.000   1.000
37  ELA ~~  ELA  1.000  0 NA     NA        1        1   0.000  0.000   0.000
38  ELP ~~  ELP  1.000  0 NA     NA        1        1   1.000  1.000   1.000
39  ELC ~~  ELC  1.000  0 NA     NA        1        1   0.000  1.000   1.000
...
```

Looking at tutorials (e.g., [Tutorial][1]), there should normally be three additional rows indicating the correlations between the subscales ELA, ELP, and ELC, looking something like this:

```
40 ELA ~~ ELP ...
41 ELA ~~ ELC ...
42 ELP ~~ ELC ...
```

However, these correlations do not show up. I tried it with different latent variables in my dataset, but always only got the correlations like rows 36 to 39 in my example). What do I do wrong? How can I make the correlations of the subscales show up? Is there another way to access them?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: correlations among the latent factors `ELA`, `ELP`and `ELC` are confounded within your global factor `EL`. If you would try to specifically include the computation of correlation components (e.g., `ELA~~ELP`) you would get a warning message that the model is not identified.